# Ruby on rails - "cannot load Java class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jdbc, db2, jrubyonrails

I am using:

1. Ubuntu 12.04 LTC
2. JRuby 1.7.2
3. Rails 3.2.12
4. DB2 C express 10.1

My database.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
  url: localhost:50001/devdb
  host: localhost
  port: 50001
  database: devdb
  username: db2inst1
  password: mypass
```

But in when I stats my server and open the home page "localhost:3000/" and click on "About your application’s environment" I get the following error:

```
cannot load Java class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Could you advice?

The only thing that I have found as suggestion was to add the driver in my JRUBY_HOME/bin/ folder but this do not solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy `db2jcc.jar` and `db2jcc_license_cu.jar` to `jruby/lib directory`.

You are getting that error because you need the DB2 Universal JDBC driver jars in your classpath

Comment: I am not able to find it. I am using "rvm use jruby" command to locate  the jruby folder.Unfortunately, there is no /lib directory in it.

Comment: check under ~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-*/lib

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's save my problem. By why "rvm use jruby" redirect me to other jruby folder?

Comment: Your RVM was installed on user account because your root account was not used, then RVM did a configuration on your user folder and now RVM will do all management in the user folder. For more information please read on RVM web site.